# Toshiba satellite notebook: periodic processor load up to 70% by System process

Tags: windows-7

I've bought my laptop (Toshiba satellite, windows 7 Home Premium 64bit) about 6 months ago, and till now have a problem: evetually processor is loaded up to 70% by System process.
If I catch that moment, I can see multiple threads in System process via Process Explorer, many of them in ntoskrnl.exe!KeAcquireInStackQueuedSpinLockAtDpcLevel+0x1e0, and one of these consumes 50% of CPU time (I don't know who eats other 20%).
This activity lasts for a few seconds and until it ends any opened program is running very slow, flash player freezes.

Does anyone can suggest how I can get rid of this problem?

Comment: what I get from the web so far is: It is likly to be a driver item. it is designed to takeover to get something done, it is kernal based (low level) and probably hardware based somehow.  If possible to test and discover: Remove any things plugged in external you dont need,  disable any specific driver items for testing.

Comment: Thank you for response. I haven't any device plugged into my notebook except of a power cable.

Comment: I have my notebook stuffed with toshiba software (lots of it don't even visible and running in background). I think that this zoo of toshibaware is somehow compete with OS services.

Comment: I do not know. MS tells other developers to use that method only when nessisary, but they would be the first ones to break thier own rules they place on others :-)  Another place to look would be in the Resources monitor for the disk activity.  the disk activity shows what file , and what program/process, and it has a slow decay rate for the visual data, so a person can see what happens.  The files it is accessing or writing might provide more clues.

Comment: I'm not sure what was it, but since then I extended RAM from 3 gigs to 8. Now almost everything works smoothly.